# Vague error with Azure DevOps web app deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to use an Azure App Service Deploy task in Azure DevOps to deploy a file to an app service in Azure. I have been able to use this release pipeline to deploy to the same app service in the past. Two things have changed: I had to re-make the build machine (which exists in Azure), and the source code moved from Azure DevOps to GitLab.

The error I am running into is:

```
Error: (3/21/2019 4:34:45 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.  
Error: The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
```

Well, I'm the server admin, and I don't have a clue.
Is there some log file I can look at for more information? Can someone please offer some suggestions?
I'm happy to provide additional information, I'm just not sure what would help at this point.

Comment: Have you tried to [set `system.debug` true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#get-logs-to-diagnose-problems) to get the detail logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tom Sun for directing me to the system.debug variable. That was very helpful.  When I turned on the debugging the release worked, witch really doesn't make sense. I started the build machine after it had automatically shut down the day before, but then I had also rebooted the machine eight or nine times before that.
I removed the debug variable and the release still works.
I have no satisfying answer to how this issue was resolved and I don't know how to get the system in a state to reproduce the error.
An additional finding I have is that the artifact produced by the original build was a corrupt war file. Perhaps that had something to do with it?